# Cannot upload an App Bundle on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I tried to upload an App Bundle (for a new app) on the Google Play. Google asked me to enable App Signing. Fine, I choose to enable it, I download their PEPK tool and use it to generate a ZIP (with a keystore that I have created to export my App Bundle). The ZIP contains two files : "encryptedPrivateKey" and "certificate.pem". I upload that ZIP file on Google Play and now it says "Google App signing successfully enabled".

So now, I export my App Bundle using the same keystore and try to upload it on Google Play and the result is "You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users.". Okay, so I create a new keystore but now I have an "Incorrect SHA1" error.

My question is : what was my mistake and how can I solve this problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not think to create an app bundle is tricky. Simply, create an app bundle via Android studio, create or enter the previous password and just create a new release putting app bundle in the required box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally managed to upload my App Bundle on Google Play. The solution was to delete my release and create another one. Then, I uploaded my App Bundle signed with the first keystore and it worked.